# Why Docker Image getting so large for node js app

Tags: node.js, docker

here is the screenshoot of my Dockerfile:
[image]

And this is my Docker image file:
[image]

why I getting large docker image using this Dockerfile command eventhough I have add the .dockerignore to ignore node modules, is there any way to solve this image size ? Can we use webpack to bundle and implement tree shaking and make the size smaller for prodction

Answer (score 6):

1. To reduce the docker image size, use the `alpine` tag.
   this tag uses Alpine Linux as a base image, and this will decrease your built image. (What is Alpine Linux? Alpine Linux is a security-oriented, **lightweight Linux distribution** based on musl, libc, and busybox.)
2. you can use multi-stage builds to build your docker image.
3. use `npm prune --production`, this command will remove the packages specified in your devDependencies.

A sample `Dockerfile` that follows the mentioned conditions:

```
FROM node:14-alpine as build

WORKDIR /opt/app

COPY . /opt/app

RUN npm ci \
    && npm run build \
    && npm prune --production


FROM node:14-alpine

ENV NODE_ENV=production

USER node
WORKDIR /opt/app

COPY --from=build /opt/app/package*.json /opt/app/
COPY --from=build /opt/app/node_modules/ /opt/app/node_modules/
COPY --from=build /opt/app/dist/ /opt/app/dist/

EXPOSE 3000

CMD ["npm", "run", "start:prod"]
```

Comment: may you provide a simple `Dockerfile`?

Comment: Alternatively, `npm ci --omit=dev` can be used instead of `npm ci` and `npm prune --production`.

Answer (score 0):

you can use `alpine` docker image like `node:14.5.0-alpine`

its recommended using alpine images as it's  speed, secure, and lightweight

Comment: when doing RUN npm install, it make a node modules right and then do COPY . . , is COPY . . mean the docker copy all of the source including the node modules into docker image ? but actually I have ignore node modules in .dockerignore file